# Trouble using an image in a Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, graphics, errors, pdftex

I'm trying to include an image in my Beamer presentation, but I keep getting this error:

> !pdfTeX error: /usr/local/texlive/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex (file
>   ./markov.jpeg): reading JPEG image failed (no JPEG header found)

As per the template given on writelatex.com, I'm using the following code to install the image:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{markov.jpeg}
    \caption{\label{fig 1:}Repeated Iteration of Markov Matrix}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). See this topic to familiarize more with our format: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Can we rule out the file is in fact broken? What does `file ./markov.jpeg` say when executed on the command line? Does it open in `xv`, `gimp`, your browser?

Comment: Was the file a png (or something else) once, and you just changed the file extension?

Comment: The file has always been a jpeg.   It opens fine in the browser as well.

Comment: Btw: Drop the file extension from your `\includegraphics`.

Comment: make sure it is a `.jpeg` and not a `.jpg`. Depending on the system it may be important whether or not the file extension is in capital letters

Answer (score 4):

The error message means that the file `markov.jpeg` is not really a `.jpeg`-file. The fact that it opens fine in the browser does not mean much (if the browser fails to load it as jpeg, it tries using other supported formats to decode it).

To fix the problem, open it with a more or less advanced image editing/viewing progam (Gimp, MS Paint, Picasa, MS Office Picture Manager, Windows Live Photo Gallery or Photoshop to name a few), and use the export command to create a new `.jpeg` file.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, following the advise from the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173233/241850) above. It wasn't really JPEG. So I took the actions bellow.

If you are using bash. Check it out the file format with:

```
file markov.jpeg
```

Later you can convert it to real JPEG, using `ImageMagick`.

```
convert markov.jpeg markov.jpeg
```